# QL table to FLUX table conversion

Tags: grafana, influxdb, influxql, flux-influxdb

I currently have the following in ql in grafana :

```
SELECT Last("Capacity") AS "Capacity","Freespace",("Freespace"/"Capacity") *100 AS "PercentFree" 
FROM "ExtensionData.Guest.Disk" WHERE ("VM" =~ /^$VM$/) AND $timeFilter GROUP BY "VM","Path","Ownership","Exemption"
```

which produces a table of the LAST value for each path on each vm like:

[image]

moving into a flux query version i have cobbled together something like:

```
from(bucket: "vmdiskcapacity")
|> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
|> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "ExtensionData.Guest.Disk")
|> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "Capacity" or r["_field"] == "Freespace")
|> group(columns: ["VM","Path","Ownership","Exemption"])
|> aggregateWindow(every: v.windowPeriod, fn: last, createEmpty: false)
|> last()
```

but the table now only show one at a time is this something to do with the grouping or my query?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Problem was not with FLux query but how Grafana displays the table, using some transforms within Grafana I was able to display the same table as the QL query